# Python - Unusual "Index Out of Range" while reading from USB

Tags: python, indexing, usb, hid

Happy new Year together,

normaly, i try to solve everything myself, to keep my grey Mushroom alive.
But in this case im really stuck...

**My Task:**

- Read from an USB Device
- Create an Animation based in Data of an analog Axis

**Problem:**

- It works on one PC while in pyCharm, also as EXE
- Index Out of Range on other PC´s

**Info**

- Error belongs to Line 82 - Read_X2 = readout[2]
- Console shows successful line of the USB List
- Programm isnt frozen while Error (OK Print Button works)
- I started Coding 3 Days ago... So i made it like this, becouse im still to stupide
  to end a "while" without closing my Programm...
  Also List-"Drehung" could be made more elegant. But my first intention for the error
  was about my auto counting "range" creation. So i deleted it and made it this way.
  Meanwhile i know, its from my USB List.

I bet, its a dead simple Problem. I just overlooking something.
Youre also allowed to laugh about it if you tell me the solution afterwards.

Greetings Emanresu

My Code Salad:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import hid

# START Part to avoid Problems with "One File"

import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get the absolute path to the resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
       base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# END Part to avoid Problems with "One File"


win = Tk("Test")
win.geometry("460x410")
win.config(bg="grey")
Btn = Button(win, text="ok", activebackground='gray', bg='grey', bd=0)

# Choose a "Path"- Option for "One Directory" or "One File"

# path = "./Animation/"
path = (resource_path("Animation/"))

List = ['000.png',
        '001.png', '002.png', '003.png', '004.png', '005.png', '006.png', '007.png', '008.png', '009.png', '010.png',
        '011.png', '012.png', '013.png', '014.png', '015.png', '016.png', '017.png', '018.png', '019.png', '020.png',
        '021.png', '022.png', '023.png', '024.png', '025.png', '026.png', '027.png', '028.png', '029.png', '030.png',
        '031.png', '032.png', '033.png', '034.png', '035.png', '036.png', '037.png', '038.png', '039.png', '040.png',
        '041.png', '042.png', '043.png', '044.png', '045.png', '046.png', '047.png', '048.png', '049.png', '050.png',
        '051.png', '052.png', '053.png', '054.png', '055.png', '056.png', '057.png', '058.png', '059.png', '060.png',
        '061.png', '062.png', '063.png', '064.png', '065.png', '066.png', '067.png', '068.png', '069.png', '070.png',
        '071.png', '072.png', '073.png', '074.png', '075.png', '076.png', '077.png', '078.png', '079.png', '080.png',
        '081.png', '082.png', '083.png', '084.png', '085.png', '086.png', '087.png', '088.png', '089.png', '090.png',
        '091.png', '092.png', '093.png', '094.png', '095.png', '096.png', '097.png', '098.png', '099.png', '100.png',
        '101.png', '102.png', '103.png', '104.png', '105.png', '106.png', '107.png', '108.png', '109.png', '110.png',
        '111.png', '112.png', '113.png', '114.png', '115.png', '116.png', '117.png', '118.png', '119.png', '120.png',
        '121.png', '122.png', '123.png', '124.png', '125.png', '126.png', '127.png', '128.png', '129.png', '130.png',
        '131.png', '132.png', '133.png', '134.png', '135.png', '136.png', '137.png', '138.png', '139.png', '140.png',
        '141.png', '142.png', '143.png', '144.png', '145.png', '146.png', '147.png', '148.png', '149.png', '150.png',
        '151.png', '152.png', '153.png', '154.png', '155.png', '156.png', '157.png', '158.png', '159.png', '160.png',
        '161.png', '162.png', '163.png', '164.png', '165.png', '166.png', '167.png', '168.png', '169.png', '170.png',
        '171.png', '172.png', '173.png', '174.png', '175.png', '176.png', '177.png', '178.png', '179.png', '180.png',
        '181.png', '182.png', '183.png', '184.png', '185.png', '186.png', '187.png', '188.png', '189.png', '190.png',
        '191.png', '192.png', '193.png', '194.png', '195.png', '196.png', '197.png', '198.png', '199.png', '200.png',
        '201.png', '202.png', '203.png', '204.png', '205.png', '206.png', '207.png', '208.png', '209.png', '210.png',
        '211.png', '212.png', '213.png', '214.png', '215.png', '216.png', '217.png', '218.png', '219.png', '220.png',
        '221.png', '222.png', '223.png', '224.png', '225.png', '226.png', '227.png', '228.png', '229.png', '230.png',
        '231.png', '232.png', '233.png', '234.png', '235.png', '236.png', '237.png', '238.png', '239.png', '240.png',
        '241.png', '242.png', '243.png', '244.png', '245.png', '246.png', '247.png', '248.png', '249.png', '250.png',
        '251.png', '252.png', '253.png', '254.png', '255.png', '256.png', '257.png', '258.png', '259.png', '260.png',
        ]


# Creating Canvas for the Animation
def to_pil2(img, button, x, y, w, h):
    image = Image.open(img)
    image = image.resize((w, h))
    pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    button['image'] = pic
    button.image = pic
    button.place(x=x, y=y)


# Optional Visualisation of Readout
label = Label(win, font=('Stencil', 30, 'bold'), bg='grey', fg='black')
label.place(x=5, y=5)


# Collecting Date from USB-Device
# Col0=unknown, Col1+2= X-Axis, Col3+4= Y-Axis, Col5+6= Z-Axis, Col7+8+9= Analog unused, Col10= Buttons
def run():
    simpad = hid.device()
    simpad.open(0x2341, 0x8037)
    simpad.set_nonblocking(True)

    readout = simpad.read(11)
    # read_x1 = readout[1]
    read_x2 = readout[2]
    # read_multiply = (read_x2 * 256)
    # read_full = (read_multiply + read_X1)
    # animation = (read_full / 700) #Option For smoother Movement

# Drawing Animation + Number on Canvas
    to_pil2(path + List[int(read_x2)], Btn, 5, 5, 450, 400)
    label['text'] = read_x2
    win.after(10, run)
    print(readout)


# Pray
run()
Btn["command"] = lambda: print('Freeze-test')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: As your code looks like `python`(?), I'd suggest to add that Tag to your question so that readers would see

Comment: Oh, yure right, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with all the libraries you are using but I have done I/O stuff before.  Just glancing at the code I see you are doing a  nonblocking read (you called `set_nonblocking` with True).  Therefore, you either need to handle the case when no data or a smaller amount of data is read, or you need to change your code to do a blocking read, which will wait until all 11 bytes have been read.

Comment: I set it to "False" and it works! Thank you so much!
I thought the "nonblocking" funktion is to keep the device open for other software.

But im still curious:
While direktly parsing simpad.read(11) i allways see all 11 Bits.
And why is it a problem on one PC, but works on another? Delay?

PS: Cant give you an "Arrow up" my Reputation is still to low, im sorry.

Comment: Nonblocking has nothing to do with that other thing you're talking about.  I think you meant "bytes" instead of "bits".  I would guess that simpad.read sometimes returns an empty array, and maybe you are not printing that properly, so you think it always returns 11 bytes.  Obviously `readout` doesn't have 11 bytes if `readout[2]` is out of range.  And yeah, different PCs have different USB drivers and USB hardware so there can be subtle differences in the timing of when data is available.  Especially if they are running different operating systems (which you haven't specified).

Comment: Allright, learned alot here! Thank you!
Yep, bytes ofcourse. App is for Win7 to 10. Thats also, why i have to works with an outdated version of Phyton. Also sometimes a Problem when searching for Problems.